# Unable to parse JSON from server api

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, api, afnetworking-3

I am using `AFNetworking` to get a post api response from server by the following code

```
void (^AuthLoginCompleteBlock)(BOOL success, NSString *message, NSDictionary *response, NSError *error);
-(void)login:(NSString *)user password:(NSString *)password deviceID:(NSString *)deviceID callback:(authRequestCompleteBlock)callback{

    AuthLoginCompleteBlock = callback;
    NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:user,@"data[User][username]]",password,@"data[User][password]]",deviceID,@"data[User][device_id]]", nil];

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc]initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"text/html", nil];
    [manager POST:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",SERVER_URL,LOGIN] parameters:parameters progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",responseObject];

        AuthLoginCompleteBlock(YES,str,nil,nil);
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

        AuthLoginCompleteBlock(NO,error.description,nil,nil);
    }];
    NSLog(@"param = %@",parameters);
}
```

Now the URL working fine and everything seems fine but the problem is response is coming through `message` string I created in `AuthLoginCompleteBlock` block and `NSDictionary` response is coming `NULL` and it seems something like this (message string)

```
{
    message = "Please enter valid email related to your account.";
    status = failed;
}
```

While trying to fetch like this

```
NSData *jsonData = [message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            NSError *error = nil;
            id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
            if(!error) {
                NSLog(@"hello = %@", json);
            }
            else{
                NSLog(@"errr = %@",error.description);
            }
```

got the following error

Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No string key for value in object around character 6." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No string key for value in object around character 6. Which means the Json format is incorrect from server? But in postman the response is following and pretty fine

```
{
  "status": "failed",
  "message": "Please enter valid email related to your account."
}
```

If I left out something please comment.

Answer (score 1):

Well the problem was I was already getting a dictionary so I would have no need to parse it. The bug is these two lines.

```
 NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",responseObject];

 AuthLoginCompleteBlock(YES,str,nil,nil);
```

I was sending string to my block which is already a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
        manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];

        NSDictionary *parameters = @{
                                     @"user": @"login",

                                     @"password": txtFieldPassword.text,

                                     @"device": @"ios",
                                     @"deviceToken": strToken,


                                     };


        NSLog(@"parameters is ====%@",parameters);
        manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer
                                      serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];
        [manager POST:@"yourUrl" parameters:parameters progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject)

        {

            NSLog(@"success!%@",responseObject);
            [self successfullLogin:responseObject];


        } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error)
        {
            NSLog(@"error: %@", error);


        }];
```

Comment: Seems like AFNetworking 3.0 does not have AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.

Comment: Yes AFHTTPRequestOperationManager is not included in pod AFNetworking 3.0